# ASP.NET Error when sending a list data from code-behind to aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, stack-overflow, code-behind

I get `StackOverflowException` in `Page_Load`, The website is loading forever with a blank page and this error appears.:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please post your code in your question instead of providing an external link to it. External links tend to break over time and then the question becomes worthless to the community. Also, text in images is not searchable which also doesn't help the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return `places` property from `places` property, overflowing your stack. Change your property to:

```
protected List<Place> Places { get; set; }
```

And in Page_Load:

```
Places = new List<Place> { ... };
```

Comment: @HữuLinh no problem